# ANTLR lexer rule consumes characters even if not matched?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I've got a strange side effect of an antlr lexer rule and I've created an (almost) minimal working example to demonstrate it.
In this example I want to match the String `[0..1]` for example. But when I debug the grammar the token stream that reaches the parser only contains `[..1]`. The first integer, no matter how many digits it contains is always consumed and I've got no clue as to how that happens. If I remove the `FLOAT` rule everything is fine so I guess the mistake lies somewhere in that rule. But since it shouldn't match anything in `[0..1]` at all I'm quite puzzled.

I'd be happy for any pointers where I might have gone wrong. This is my example:

```
grammar min;
options{
language = Java;
output = AST;
ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
backtrack = true;
}
tokens {
  DECLARATION;
}

declaration : LBRACEVAR a=INTEGER DDOTS b=INTEGER RBRACEVAR -> ^(DECLARATION $a $b);

EXP : 'e' | 'E';
LBRACEVAR: '[';
RBRACEVAR: ']';
DOT: '.';
DDOTS: '..';

FLOAT
    : INTEGER DOT POS_INTEGER
    | INTEGER DOT POS_INTEGER EXP INTEGER
    | INTEGER EXP INTEGER
    ;

INTEGER : POS_INTEGER | NEG_INTEGER;
fragment NEG_INTEGER : ('-') POS_INTEGER;
fragment POS_INTEGER : NUMBER+;
fragment NUMBER: ('0'..'9');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `'0'` is discarded by the lexer and the following errors are produced:

```
line 1:3 no viable alternative at character '.'
line 1:2 extraneous input '..' expecting INTEGER
```

This is because when the lexer encounters `'0.'`, it tries to create a `FLOAT` token, but can't. And since there is no other rule to fall back on to match `'0.'`, it produces the errors, discards `'0'` and creates a `DOT` token.

This is simply how ANTLR's lexer works: it will not backtrack to match an `INTEGER` followed by a `DDOTS` (note that `backtrack=true` only applies to parser rules!).

Inside the `FLOAT` rule, you must make sure that when a double `'.'` is ahead, you produce a `INTEGER` token instead. You can do that by adding a syntactic predicate (the `('..')=>` part) and produce `FLOAT` tokens only when a single `'.'` is followed by a digit (the `('.' DIGIT)=>` part). See the following demo:

```
declaration
 : LBRACEVAR INTEGER DDOTS INTEGER RBRACEVAR
 ;

LBRACEVAR : '[';
RBRACEVAR : ']';
DOT       : '.';
DDOTS     : '..';

INTEGER
 : DIGIT+
 ;

FLOAT
 : DIGIT+ ( ('.' DIGIT)=> '.' DIGIT+ EXP? 
          | ('..')=>      {$type=INTEGER;} // change the token here
          |               EXP
          )
 ;

fragment EXP   : ('e' | 'E') DIGIT+;
fragment DIGIT : ('0'..'9');
```

Comment: Now that was an (for me at least) unexpected behavior. Thanks for the comprehensive example, I've got it all up and running now :-)

Comment: @Lichtblitz, you're welcome, and yeah, tokenizing `..` (in combination with with INT- and FLOAT-tokens) is tricky! :)